# State value keeps reverting back

Tags: reactjs

I have `teamId` property in my `state`. I try to change the `teamId` property with a click of a button. I then log my `teamId` and display it through an HTML label. My `teamId` **keeps reverting back to the old default value**. The label where I display the state switches back and forth when the button is clicked.

```
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      teamId: 0,
      profile: ''
    }
    this.changeTeamProfile = this.changeTeamProfile.bind(this);
  }

  changeTeamProfile() {
    console.log('Changed')
    this.setState({teamId:1});
  }

render() {
<Router>
 <label>{this.state.teamId}</label>
 <Route path="/setupnewuser">
    <div>
        <button onClick={this.changeTeamProfile}> Save </button>
    </div>
  </Route>
</Router>
}
export default App
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `<button />` element (with most browsers) has a default 'type' attribute set to "submit," which means that when you click your button there are a number of default behaviors that you will need to opt-out of. Try changing your code to

```
<button type="button" onClick={this.changeTeamProfile}> Save </button>
```

Comment: Brendan Bond It worked. Thank you for the information. I still don't understand what was happening though. Do you have any article or info site where I can read more about it? Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type